# What's happening behind the scenes with v-container, v-layout, and v-flex?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm new to UI frameworks and am slightly familiar with CSS and Flexbox. I'm starting to piece together Vuetify tags to create my components but I would like a detailed description of what's happening on the backend when using these tags. Also, it would be nice to see a few differing examples that show how they can be used to create components.

Thanks in advance.